# Desktop in Window Switcher

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

In the past, by default, Ubuntu included the Desktop in the Window Switcher. Now, (Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS), does not offer the Desktop in the Window Switcher.  How do I get this small, but very important feature, back?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't, unless a Gnome Shell extension providing the feature would exist. I am not aware of any, though.

Alternatives to quickly hide all windows are

- to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>
- to install the Gnome Shell extension [Show Desktop Button](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1194/show-desktop-button/) by JSZVB, which places an icon in the topbar.